# I want a PyTorch model that uses different layers conditionally

Tags: pytorch

I'm sorry if this question is somewhere out there, I can't seem to get anything.

I know this could be accomplished by having separate models, but I would like a single model that employs different layers depending on the input. Something like:

```
def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs_arr):
    self.linear = []
    for n_outputs in n_outputs_arr:
        self.linear.append(nn.Linear(n_inputs, n_outputs))

def forward(self, x, i):
    return self.linear[i](x)
```

and of course, to only update the weights on the `i`'th layer (batches will only consist of a single `i`). Is that a thing?

Comment: The code shown should work, what's the issue?

Comment: don't use python `list` for `nn` objects. use `nn.ModuleList`. check [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-difference-in-usage-between-nn-modulelist-and-python-list/7744) out